# Why ghidra does not use label variables and uses constants to represent code local variables?

Tags: ghidra

so the question is in the title I had a simple C program to understand how global and local variables(struct) are stored in the stack. The problem is I don't know if this is good or bad or if I'm doing something bad but why does Ghidra here use use constant instead of a label variable. Like this is much harder to apply the struct data type and make the disassemble more readable like in IDA.

[image: Ghidra Example]
Ghidra Example

[image: IDA same code]

IDA Example

After applying struct is much more readable:
[image: struct data type]

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if this is just plain normal?